# Error running Fuction(s,e) in Web Form with Master Page in Asp.Net

Tags: asp.net

I am using a combo box (outside the grid) to filter a Grid content. The code works just fine in a stand alone Web Form. However, when the same code runs in a Web From with a Master Page and I change selection in the combo box, I am getting error: "0x800a1391 - JavaScript runtime error: 'TimesheetGrid' is undefined" for TimesheetGrid.PerformCallback(s.GetValue()). Any idea what I am doing wrong and how to fix it? Thank you very much for your time and energy!

Working Web Form:

```
<%@ Page Language="vb" AutoEventWireup="false"
CodeBehind="PayPeriodTest.aspx.vb" Inherits="TTS.PayPeriodTest" %>

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
<title></title>
</head>
<body>
<form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>
        <dx:ASPxComboBox ID="BoxPayPeriods" runat="server"    DataSourceID="SqlPayPeriods" EnableClientSideAPI="True" TextField="PayRange" ValueField="PayPeriodKey">
            <ClientSideEvents
                SelectedIndexChanged="function(s, e) { TimesheetGrid.PerformCallback(s.GetValue()); }">
            </ClientSideEvents>
        </dx:ASPxComboBox>

        <dx:ASPxGridView ID="TimesheetGrid" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" DataSourceID="SqlTimesheet" KeyFieldName="RecordID">
            <Columns>
                <dx:GridViewDataTextColumn FieldName="RecordID" ReadOnly="True" VisibleIndex="0">
                    <EditFormSettings Visible="False" />
                </dx:GridViewDataTextColumn>
                <dx:GridViewDataTextColumn FieldName="ShipCountry" VisibleIndex="1">
                </dx:GridViewDataTextColumn>
                <dx:GridViewDataTextColumn FieldName="PayPeriodID" VisibleIndex="2">
                </dx:GridViewDataTextColumn>
            </Columns>
        </dx:ASPxGridView>
        <br />
        <asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlTimesheet" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:prd_ttsConnectionString %>" SelectCommand="SELECT RecordID, ShipCountry, PayPeriodID FROM TIMESHEET WHERE (PayPeriodID = @Param1)">
            <SelectParameters>
                <asp:SessionParameter DefaultValue="6" Name="Param1" SessionField="PayPeriod" />
            </SelectParameters>
        </asp:SqlDataSource>
        <br />
        <asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlPayPeriods" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:prd_ttsConnectionString %>" SelectCommand="SELECT * FROM [vw_PayPeriods]"></asp:SqlDataSource>
    </div>
</form>
```

Non Working Web Form with a Master Page:

```
<%@ Page Title="" Language="vb" AutoEventWireup="false" MasterPageFile="~/Main.master" CodeBehind="PayPeriodSub.aspx.vb" Inherits="TTS.PayPeriodSub" %>

<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent" runat="server">

<dx:ASPxComboBox ID="BoxPayPeriods" runat="server" DataSourceID="SqlPayPeriods" EnableClientSideAPI="True" TextField="PayRange" ValueField="PayPeriodKey">
    <ClientSideEvents 
        SelectedIndexChanged="function(s, e) { TimesheetGrid.PerformCallback(s.GetValue()); }">
    </ClientSideEvents>
</dx:ASPxComboBox>

<dx:ASPxGridView ID="TimesheetGrid" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" DataSourceID="SqlTimesheet" KeyFieldName="RecordID">
    <Columns>
        <dx:GridViewDataTextColumn FieldName="RecordID" ReadOnly="True" VisibleIndex="0">
            <EditFormSettings Visible="False" />
        </dx:GridViewDataTextColumn>
        <dx:GridViewDataTextColumn FieldName="ShipCountry" VisibleIndex="1">
        </dx:GridViewDataTextColumn>
        <dx:GridViewDataTextColumn FieldName="PayPeriodID" VisibleIndex="2">
        </dx:GridViewDataTextColumn>
    </Columns>
</dx:ASPxGridView>
<br />
<asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlTimesheet" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:prd_ttsConnectionString %>" SelectCommand="SELECT RecordID, ShipCountry, PayPeriodID FROM TIMESHEET WHERE (PayPeriodID = @Param1)">
    <SelectParameters>
        <asp:SessionParameter DefaultValue="6" Name="Param1" SessionField="PayPeriod" />
    </SelectParameters>
</asp:SqlDataSource>
<br />
    <asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlPayPeriods" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$  ConnectionStrings:prd_ttsConnectionString %>" SelectCommand="SELECT * FROM [vw_PayPeriods]"></asp:SqlDataSource>
</asp:Content>
```

[Click here to see the error screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sVyJB.jpg)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because, when you use master page, the ID which is rendered to client wil be "TimesheetGrid". Therefore the javascript does not recognize the control with the ID you have provided.

You have two ways to resolve the issue.

1. using ClientIDMode="Static".

   ```
   <dx:ASPxGridView ID="TimesheetGrid" ClientIDMode="Static" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" DataSourceID="SqlTimesheet" KeyFieldName="RecordID">
       <Columns>
   ```

   Use ClientIDMode="Static" only if your web form(including master page or other user controls) has unique ID.
2. Use `"<%=TimesheetGrid.ClientID%>"` to get the exact client ID which is rendered to client.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thank you Anoop! That was it!!! Regarding option 2, where would I add that line? Sorry for the silly question but I am new to this.

Comment: In your function where you have used the ID. TimesheetGrid.PerformCallback